How to implement Veritcal Trim from Figma in Android
We are building a new Design System and designers proposed to use Figma's new feature Vertical Trim to better manage margins.
So far, I haven't been able to find a way to implement it in native Android.
I've found this thread Android: TextView: Remove spacing and padding on top and bottom which suggested using android:includeFontPadding="false" but:

It doesn't work with language-specific letters like Ś or Ć (it crops off the accent)
It still leaves padding at the bottom

Also, I have found an article about this on google's fonts website https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/using_type/vertical_spacing_and_line_height_in_design_systems
It states, that CSS is soon to release a leading-trim feature that will enable trimming text "much like you can on Android" - I haven't found the Android solution though.
Image form the article illustrating the problem:

Is this possible to achieve in Android?
